# Google Appscript using for loop with if

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The aim of my script is to loop through one column of data (Col 2 in my example) and where the cell says 'Approved' then adjust the formula which is sitting in the corresponding Col1 to be saved as a value. The script below achieves this but runs awfully slowly - can anyone help in speeding it up?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var data = ss.getSheetByName('data');
var tracker = ss.getSheetByName('Tracker');
var rowlength = tracker.getLastRow();

for (r=2; r<rowlength+1; r++) {
 
 var ApprovedCell = tracker.getRange(r,2).getValue();
 
 if (ApprovedCell == 'Approved'){
    var FormulaCell = tracker.getRange(r,1);
    FormulaCell.copyTo(FormulaCell,{contentsOnly:true});
  
 }}
}
```

Comment: Just in case. Perhaps you need no script at all. You can use `=IF()` formula. Put in the cells of column A something like this: `=IF(B2="Approved", C2*2+D2, "")` . That means: the cell will contain C2*2+D2  if cell B2 contains 'Approved', else cell C2 will contain nothing.

Comment: @YuriKhristich the OP **did not** say that he wants **nothing** when B column is `"Approved"`. He cleary said, he wants to replace the formula with **its** value. So he needs a particular value there, not an empty string.

Comment: Yep thats right @Marios - thank you. Your solution is great

Comment: Glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The issue with your current solution is that you are iteratively using `getValue`, `getRange` and `copyTo` which is an extremely inefficient approach especially when the size of the data becomes large.
- Instead you can use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas) to get **all** the values and the formulas respectively, of the given range, and then use [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to set **all** the desired values/formulas back to the sheet.
- The following script will iterate over the values with a [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and will store the value, `if` cell in column **B** is `'Approved'`, otherwise store the formula, to an empty array `repAr`.
- Then you can efficiently use a single line of code to set **all** the values/formulas back to column **A**:
  `tracker.getRange(2,1,repAr2D.length,1).setValues(repAr2D);`

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const tracker = ss.getSheetByName('Tracker');
  const vals = tracker.getRange('A2:B'+tracker.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const formulas = tracker.getRange('A2:A'+tracker.getLastRow()).getFormulas().flat();
  const repAr = [];
  vals.forEach((r,i)=>
  repAr.push(r[1]=='Approved'?r[0]:formulas[i]));
  const repAr2D = repAr.map(r=>[r]);
  tracker.getRange('A2:A'+tracker.getLastRow()).clearContent();
  tracker.getRange(2,1,repAr2D.length,1).setValues(repAr2D);
}
```

---

**Bonus info:**

- Instead of a regular `if` condition, I used a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20(ternary)%20operator%20is,if%20the%20condition%20is%20falsy.) to make the code more clear.
- `getFormulas()` returns a 2D array and this is why I am using [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert it to a 1D array. This is more convenient given that the range is a single column and you can just slice the array with a single index.
- It is a good practice to [clear the content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) before you set data to a range that already contains some data.